# Display the first 8 portfolios

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm new to Wordpress, just wondering whether I could retrieve 8 latest portfolios?

Since I have too many portfolios, the page load is so slow, so I would like to display the first 8 only.

Answer (score 0):

To list the portfolio please add the below code in the current active theme **functions.php** file and the use the **shortcode** **[portfolio-grid-custom posts_per_page="8"]** at any pages.

```
function create_grid_layout_portfolio($attr){


    $posts_per_page     =   $attr['posts_per_page'];
    $paged              =   (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         =>  'portfolio',
        'orderby'           =>  'date',
        'order'             =>  'ASC',
        'posts_per_page'    =>  $posts_per_page,
        'paged'             =>  $paged
    );
    //[portfolio-grid-custom posts_per_page="4"]
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>
    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php 
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {?>
        <ul class="custom-col-<?php echo $num_of_col;?>" id="loop_portfolio_custom" >   
            <?php while ($query->have_posts()) { $query->the_post(); 
                    global $post;
                    $post_id            =   $post->ID;
                    $featured_img_url   =   get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id,'full');
                    $args               =   array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'names');
                    $product_terms      =   wp_get_object_terms( $post_id,  'portfolio-types',$args );
                    $catnames           =   implode(", ",$product_terms);
                ?>
                <li> 
                    <div class="inner_portfolio" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $featured_img_url;?>);background-size: cover;background-position: center center;background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                        <div class="inner_hover" onclick='window.location.href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"'>
                            <div class="hover_show" style="display:none;">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                <span><?php echo $catnames;?></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <!-- pagination -->

            <div class="pagination">
                <?php 
                    echo paginate_links( array(
                        'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
                        'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
                        'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                        'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
                        'show_all'     => false,
                        'type'         => 'plain',
                        'end_size'     => 2,
                        'mid_size'     => 1,
                        'prev_next'    => true,
                        'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( '« Previous', 'text-domain' ) ),
                        'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Next »', 'text-domain' ) ),
                        'add_args'     => false,
                        'add_fragment' => '',
                    ) );
                ?>
            </div>
            <style>
                ul#loop_portfolio_custom {
                    margin-left: 0px;
                    margin-top: 80px;
                }
                ul#loop_portfolio_custom li {
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 33%;
                }
                .inner_portfolio {
                    width: 95%;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    height: 240px;
                    margin-top: 15px;
                    position: relative;
                }
                .inner_hover:hover {
                    opacity: .7;
                    background: #000;
                }
                .inner_hover {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    text-align:center; 
                }
                .hover_show a, .hover_show span {
                    display: inherit;
                    text-transform: capitalize;
                }
                .hover_show a{
                    font-weight: normal;
                    font-size: 39px;
                    line-height: 42px;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: white;
                }
                .hover_show span {
                    font-size: 18px;
                    line-height: 27px;
                    color: white;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    font-family: 'Open Sans';
                    font-style: normal;
                    font-weight: 300;
                }
                .hover_show {
                    position: relative;
                    top: 35%;
                    text-align: center;
                    z-index: 9999999;
                }
                .pagination a.next.page-numbers, .pagination a.prev.page-numbers {
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: #6e0d16;
                    opacity: .7;
                }
                a.page-numbers{
                    color: #6e0d16;
                    opacity: .7;
                }
                span.page-numbers.current {
                    color: #0000008f;
                }
                .pagination {
                    text-align: center;
                    padding-bottom: 30px;
                }
                .pagination span, .pagination a {
                    margin: 0 3px;
                }
            </style>    
            <?php
    }   
}
add_shortcode('portfolio-grid-custom','create_grid_layout_portfolio');
```

**Or** if you want only to limits on post get then add filter hook as mention below:

```
function wpcodex_filter_main_search_post_limits( $limit, $query ) {

    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_page('YOUR_PAGE_ID')) {
        return 'LIMIT 0, 8';
    }

    return $limit;
}
add_filter( 'post_limits', 'wpcodex_filter_main_search_post_limits', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

use your functions.php

```
// Custom Post Type

function custom_post_type_portfolio() { 

$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Portfolio', 'Post Type General Name', 'idealthinker' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'portfolio', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'idealthinker' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Portfolio', 'idealthinker' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Portfolio', 'idealthinker' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Portfolio', 'idealthinker' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Portfolio', 'idealthinker' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Portfolio Details', 'idealthinker' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'idealthinker' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Portfolio', 'idealthinker' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Portfolio', 'idealthinker' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Portfolio', 'idealthinker' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'idealthinker' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'idealthinker' ),
);

$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'portfolio', 'idealthinker' ),
    'description'         => __( 'Portfolio news and reviews', 'idealthinker' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail'), 
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'genres'),
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-generic',
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'portfolio', $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type_Portfolio', 0 );
```

//custom_pagination

```
function custom_pagination($numpages = '', $pagerange = '', $paged='') {


if (empty($pagerange)) {
    $pagerange = 2;
}

global $paged;

if (empty($paged)) {
    $paged = 1;
}

if ($numpages == '') {
    global $wp_query;

    $numpages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

    if(!$numpages) {
        $numpages = 1;
    }
}

$pagination_args = array(
    'base'            => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
    'format'          => 'page/%#%',
    'total'           => $numpages,
    'current'         => $paged,
    'show_all'        => False,
    'end_size'        => 1,
    'mid_size'        => $pagerange,
    'prev_next'       => True,
    'prev_text'       => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text'       => __('&raquo;'),
    'type'            => 'plain',
    'add_args'        => false,
    'add_fragment'    => ''
);

$paginate_links = paginate_links($pagination_args);

if ($paginate_links) {
    echo "<nav aria-label='Page navigation'>";
    //echo "<div class='left'>Page " . $paged . " of " . $numpages . "</div> ";
    echo "<div class='pagination'>" . $paginate_links . "</div> ";
    echo "</nav>";
    }
}
```

Add Your portfolio page (like page-our-portfolio.php)

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="container">
    <?php
      $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

      $my_query_args = array(
          'post_type' => 'portfolio',
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'orderby' => 'title',
          'order' => 'ASC',
          'posts_per_page' => 8,
          'paged' => $paged
      );

      $my_query = new WP_Query( $my_query_args ); ?>
    <div class="row portfolio">
        <?php while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
        $images_alt_tag = get_post_meta( $image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
        ?>

        <div class="img-box">
            <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($page->ID)) ?>">

            <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($page->ID)) ?>" alt="<?php echo $images_alt_tag; ?>">

            </a>
            <div class="title">
                <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>

    <!-- for pagination -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <?php if (function_exists('custom_pagination')) { ?>
              <?php custom_pagination($my_query->max_num_pages, "", $paged); ?>
          <?php } ?>        
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```